# Proper way to share dependencies in Karma with RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner

I use Karma and jasmine for my unit tests. I have a `main-test.js` file to configure karma, and a `main.js` to configure my application.

`main-test.js`:

```
//
...
//
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base',
  paths: {
    jquery: 'components/jquery/dist/jquery', // this is copypaste
    //another dependencies
  },
  //
  ...configuration
  //
});
```

`main.js`

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'components/jquery/dist/jquery', // this is copypaste
    //another dependencies
  },
  //
  ...configuration
  //
});
```

What is the proper way to share paths between those two configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We met the same problem with my team and ended up by requiring the main config into **test-main.js**:

```js
// requiring global requireJS config
require(['/base/config/require.conf.js'], function() {
  'use strict';

  // first require.config overload: Karma specific
  require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base/src',

    paths: {
      'angularMocks': '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks'
    },

    shim: {
      'angularMocks': {
        deps: ['angular']
      }
    }
  });

  require(['angularMocks'], function() {

    var specFiles = [];
    for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
      if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        if (/\/base\/src\/.*_test\.js$/.test(file)) {
          specFiles.push(file);
        }
      }
    }

    // second overload to include specFiles and start Karma
    require.config({
      deps: specFiles,
      callback: window.__karma__.start
    });
  });
});
```

Our starter app structure for projects using AngularJS + RequireJS is available here: [angular-requirejs-ready](https://github.com/glepretre/angular-requirejs-ready).

I do not claim this is the *proper way*, only our way ;)